# Upload de imagens salva apenas primeira imagem no banco de dados

Tags: php, pdo, imagem

Tenho o seguinte código de envio de imagens

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    //INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder     = 'upload';

    if($numFile <= 0)
        echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
    else{
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type   = $file['type'][$i];
            $size   = $file['size'][$i];
            $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";
            $identificador = $_POST['EdicaoId'];
            $UrlImagem = $folder.'/'.$novoNome;
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)){
                $SalvaUrl = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO revistas (id,url) VALUES (:id,:url)");
                    $SalvaUrl->bindParam(':id',$identificador);
                    $SalvaUrl->bindParam(':url',$UrlImagem);
                    $SalvaUrl->execute();
        }}}}
```

É salva apenas as imagens no diretório de upload, mas ao enviar para o banco de dados apenas a primeira selecionada é cadastrada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a usar o mesmo ID para inserir todas as imagens.
Eu entendo que seja isso que queres, para associar todas as imagens ao mesmo registo, mas o teu DDL está preparado para isso?
Dois inserts para o mesmo ID nessa tabela não vai violar alguma constraint?
Isso explicaria a entrada de um registo, mas mais não.

Comment: muito obrigado era isto mesmo, o ID estava definido como chave primaria.